# Не могу разобраться со Spring REST

Tags: java, spring, java-ee, spring-mvc, rest

Возникло следующее недопонимание. Допустим, у нас есть сущность Film, с которой мы взаимодействуем через Rest Controller. И допустим мы выбираем ей маппинг `"/films"`. Здесь в принципе все очевидно, что запрос на просто `/films` будет возвращать список всех фильмов, `/films/1` будет возвращать первый и так далее с остальными HTTP операциями. То есть нам надо просто сделать простейший запрос к БД и получить данные. В этой ситуации я просто передаю полученный id в сервис, он его в репозиторий и методом по типу `findOne()`получаю данные. Но! Что будет если мы например захотим класть наши фильмы только в определенные группы. Например в сущность Group, у которой будет маппинг `"/groups"`. Теперь получается, что для доступа к фильмам из определенной группы надо написать следующий запрос: `/groups/1/films`. Теперь получается, что данные так легко уже из БД получить не получится, потому что теперь нам надо будет выбирать именно те фильмы, у которых id группы соответствует тому, который указан в url'e. То есть теперь мне в репозитории придется создавать специальный метод, по типу `findOneByIdAndGroupIdEquals()`.В этом и заключается моя проблема. Мы так можем усложнять "вложенность" до бесконечности. Например, если мы захотим создать вкладку 'избранное' у пользователя, то запрос может выглядеть вообще как-то так: `users/username/favorites/1/groups/2/films/3`. В итоге я просто ума не приложу, каким образом я должен сформировать запрос к базе данных, чтобы получить именно такую выборку? Все действительно так плохо или это я просто что-то делаю неправильно?

Comment: Тут несколько нюансов: 1. вам не обязательно все реализовывать в виде GET запросов, т.е. полностью базироваться только на урле и cookies (особенно, если запрос не по типу "получить"); 2. как следствие если ваши запросы будет выглядеть так, как будто бы все ваши сущности БД связаны "все со всеми" и стандартный SQL на это плохо натягивается, то вы можете попробовать использовать какой-нибудь GrapthQL формат запросов (т.е. передавать параметры запроса в body в виде JSON) и тогда уже можно подумать на счет NoSQL БД. А если, все же, решать проблему в лоб, то вы все правильно описали, будет тяжело:)

Comment: @StateItPrimitive хорошо, спасибо

Answer (score 0):

Можно как вариант создать один endpoint /films и передавать через параметры запроса те поля, по которым фильтруем:
`http://.../films?group=3&director=Jarmush`

```
@GetMapping("/films")

public List<Film> getFilms(@RequestParam Map<String, String> headers){
        
        return FilmService.find(headers.get("group"), headers.get("director")
   }
```